# How can I communicate a value from a modal to parent using EventEmitter?

Tags: angular

I have a component that currently displays the properties of a number of objects in the form of a table. One of the features I'm trying to create for this table is the ability to select a button on a particular row and delete that row from the table. To do this the app first presents a modal to the user asking to confirm the delete, once the user has selected the tick the row should be deleted.

At the moment I have the modal working up until the point where I actually delete the row. I can delete the row fine, but I need a way for the modal to relay the ID of the row that should be deleted back to the parent so it can call `deleteRow(id)`  one of the ways I have read this is possible is by using an `EventEmitter`.

I have coded an EventEmitted into my modal component, however I am confused as to where I need to access the event from the parent. In the example shown here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction the eventemitter value is accessed by doing

```
<app-voter *ngFor="let voter of voters"
      (voted)="onVoted($event)">
    </app-voter>
```

where `app-voter` is the child and `voted` is the emitted value. However since I am using a modal I do not have an instance of my modal's template anywhere in my parent template, therefore I cannot do this. Therefore I need some other way to receive the value. What else can I do?

SessionViewerTemplate

```
<div class="session-table-container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <table class="session-table" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.sessionId}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Control</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="showDeleteModal(row)"><mat-icon><fa name="trash" size="lg"></fa></mat-icon></button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

SessionViewerComponent

```
export class SessionViewerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sessions: SessionDetail[];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'date', 'link', 'delete']
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<SessionDetail>;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.sessions);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SessionDetail>(this.sessions);
  }

  showDeleteModal(row: any): void{
    let deleteModalRef = this.dialog.open(SessionDeleteModalComponent, {
      data: {
        id: row.sessionId,
        name: row.sessionName,
      }
    });
  }

  deleteRow(index: number): void{  //<-- This is the function I need to pass the emitted ID to

    this.sessions.splice(index,1);
    console.log(this.sessions);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SessionDetail>(this.dataSource.data);
  }

}
```

SessionDeleteModalTemplate

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Are you sure you wish to delete {{data.name}}?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col delete-modal-center">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteSession()"><mat-icon><fa name="check" size="lg"></fa></mat-icon></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col delete-modal-center">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="closeDialog()"><mat-icon><fa name="times" size="lg"></fa></mat-icon></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SessionDeleteModalComponent

```
export class SessionDeleteModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() deleteIndex = new EventEmitter<number>(); //<-- Here is where I am emitting the value

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SessionDeleteModalComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  deleteSession(): void{
    this.deleteIndex.emit(this.data.sessionId);
  }

  closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `EventEmitter` is a good way to make your code reusable because your component doesn't need to know anything about the parent component, and parent component just need to bind to that event.

The problem here is that you're creating the modal component dynamically so this solution might not be ideal, at least for me.

BUT you can return data when you close the modal/ enter the delete button

So in your code I'd do something like this

SessionDeleteModalComponent:

```
  deleteSession(): void{
   // you don't need this anymore.
   // this.deleteIndex.emit(this.data.sessionId);
     this.dialogRef.close(this.data.sessionId);
  }
```

SessionViewerComponent:

```
 showDeleteModal(row: any): void{
    let deleteModalRef = this.dialog.open(SessionDeleteModalComponent, {
      data: {
        id: row.sessionId,
        name: row.sessionName,
      }
    });
   // NEW CODE HERE
   deleteModalRef.afterClosed().subscribe( id => {
       this.deleteRow(id);
   });

  }
```

Let me know if it works because this is not tested :D
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to closing the modal

```
  closeDialog(): void {
    const someData = {
        foo: "bar"
    }
    this.dialogRef.close(someData);
  }
```

```
showDeleteModal(row: any): void{
    let deleteModalRef = this.dialog.open(SessionDeleteModalComponent, {
      data: {
        id: row.sessionId,
        name: row.sessionName,
      }
    }).afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        //do something with result
    });
  }
```

If you want event happening while the modal is open, you will need to have a service that is injected into both. :)